# jQuery what is the difference between $('<p>') and $('p')

Tags: jquery

Can someone explain to me the difference between `$('<p>')` and `$('p')` in jQuery.

for example, if i write:

```
$('body').append($('<p>').html('hello my friend'));
```

then the text 'hello my friend' appears.

however, when i write:

```
$('body').append($('p').html('hello my friend'));
```

then nothing happens.

Comment: `$('p')` selects all `p` tags in the page, and then `html()` replace the innerHTML with `'hello my friend'`

Comment: $('body').append($('<p>').html('hello my friend')); means Append/create an P tag within BODY of Page.

Comment: second case likely means you don't have any existing `<p>` tags in page, otherwise you would end up with every existing `<p>` in page being moved to bottom and all would have same text `hello...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The difference:**

`$('<p>')` creates a new paragraph-element

`$('p')` select all paragraph-elements in the DOM

**Your cases:**

*Example 1:*

```
$('body').append($('<p>').html('hello my friend'));
```

Will create a new paragraph-element, give it some text, and the element will then be added to the body.

*Example 2:*

```
$('body').append($('p').html('hello my friend'));
```

Will select all paragraph-elements already present in the DOM and change their content to 'hello my friend', it will then append them all to the body, which doesn't make much sense, since they already are in the DOM.

Since nothing gets visible when you run this code, your page likely doesn't contain any `<p>` elements, so nothing matches the `$("p")` selector.

Answer (score 2):

`$('<p>')` creates a new paragraph (`<p>`) element. (`<p></p>`)

`$('p')` selects all existing paragraph elements.

For example:

```
$('p').after($('<p>').html('foo'))
```

Will select all paragraphs and add **new** paragraphs after them.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery can parse HTML an create an actual DOM element. That is, when you do something like `$("<p />")`, jQuery is parsing the markup and internally creating a DOM paragraph element that can be appended to the document.

In the other hand, jQuery integrates [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/), a CSS selector engine. The jQuery function accepts CSS selectors, meaning that `$("p")` is selecting *all paragraph elements in the document*. You can also use more complex selectors like `$("p:first-child")` and select the first paragraph of the document.

[Learn more about jQuery CSS selectors here.](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)